# How to remove header part (company details) from 2nd page of Quotes in vtiger 5.4.0

Tags: php, vtiger

im using vtiger crm 5.4.0..its awesome..
but i have 1 problem, regarding to Quotes Module, Invoice Module and other module which Generate PDF for print.
If that generated Quotes is of 3-4 pages then how to remove/hide Header part like Compny Name,logo, customer details on 2nd page?

Header part is showing on all 3-4 pages of Quotes.. Is it comes under any setting or coding part plz letme know.. in attached file i have colored that parts, i want those header in 1st page not in upcoming pages..

Thanks You.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i found best alternative to it, this tool/plugin can edit pdf as our need..
hope this work for you too..cheers..

http://forge.vtiger.com/projects/pdfmakerfree/

tutorial:
http://www.its4you.sk/images/pdf_maker/pdfmakerfree-for-vtigercrm.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Finally i solved this issue with some coding changes..

in filepath `vlib/vtiger/PDF/inventory/Headerview.php`

edit some code in that file (approx line number 26), in followinf function just add 1 condition

```
function display($parent) {
    $pdf = $parent->getPDF();
    $page2 = $pdf->getPage();

        if($page2 <= 1)
        {
             //function code goes here   
        }
}
```